# How to disable keyboard tab focus

Tags: html

Is there any way to disable disable keyboard tab focus ?

I just want to skip focusing to "bbb" when keyboard tabbing.

```
<a href="#">aaa</a>
<a href="#" tab-index="-1">bbb</a>
<a href="#">ccc</a>
<a href="#">ddd</a>
```

Comment: It's `tabindex`, actually.

Comment: luenib / Thanks problem solved lol :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost got it right. You only need to fix tab-index to tabindex. Below is the fixed html:

```html
<a href="#">aaa</a>
<a href="#" tabindex="-1">bbb</a>
<a href="#">ccc</a>
<a href="#">ddd</a>
```

It will skip the tag with text 'bbb'.